# Какая пунктуация в предложении «делать-то они делали, но...»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Предложение ***«делать-то они делали, но...»***.
Нужны ли запятые или тире, может что-то еще? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: лучше, если было бы полное предложение, но тут какие у вас сомнения?

Comment: Надо указать, есть ли знаки при повторе слов. У Розенталя есть такая тема  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104#pp104   Скорее всего, это пункт 4(2) ПО АНАЛОГИИ: 2) при повторении слова с частицей ТАК для усиления смысла: Пропаду так пропаду, всё равно! (Дост.); Свадьба так свадьба; я — Огудалова, я нищенства не допущу (Остр.); Вот это была косьба так косьба! (См.); Да так да, нет так нет; Не надо так не надо.

Answer (score 1):

***Д**елать-то они делали, но...*

• Если это *предложение*, то оно должно начинаться с большой буквы.

• Перед противительным союзом "но" по правилам ставится запятая.

• При "обрыве" предложения ставится многоточие (оно служит для обозначения прерванности речи, незаконченности высказывания).

Так что другие знаки, думаю, не нужны.

*Вот и стала к ней сноха ходить, под благовидным предлогом, уколы делать. **Делать-то она делала, но** вкалывала видно что-то не то...* ("Чайная книга" (сборник)).

***Делать-то он делал, но** постоянно возникали вещи, к которым трудно было привыкнуть* (Светлана Ломакина (из статьи)).

> — Ну вот! И все слышали! Хоть одного сейчас найди, кто не слышал! Разве что индейцы где-нибудь в Амазонии. Да и те, наверное, уже слышали.
> — **Слышать-то они слышали, но** как жить светло, не узнали.
> (Даниил Ильин. Я — террорист)

[О союзах](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/sochinitelnye-i-podchinitelnye-soyuzy)
[О многоточии](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/mnogotochie-znak-prepinaniya.html)